# What is difference between openstreetmap and openlayers?

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers-2

What is difference between openlayers & openstreetmaps ?
is openlayers made on openstreetmap or vice versa ?

Comment: Simply put, OSM is an open source collection of street, road and other features.  The end product that is most commonly used is a set of map tiles that can be consumed by a map viewer.  OpenLayers on the other hand is a JavaScript framework for displaying and manipulating spatial data in a web browser.

That's it in a nutshell, but there are many other ways they differ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the GIS SE tag descriptions note:

**OpenStreetMap (OSM)** is data

> OpenStreetMap is a collaborative project to create a free editable map
>   of the world. The data is free, and free of legal and technical
>   restrictions. OpenStreetMap is often shorted to OSM.

**OpenLayers** is a client viewer

> OpenLayers is a JavaScript library which implements an API for
>   developing dynamic map widgets on the web. The library provides tools
>   for presenting and editing geographic information using pure
>   JavaScript with no server-side dependencies.

Comment: Wel... not fully: "OpenStreetMap data is free for everyone to use. Our tile servers are not."
 

https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/